# 2D lighting from multiple point sources on GLSL ES 2.0 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

as i'm a complete noob with shaders i've got some problems while trying to get to work a 2D lighting system that basically covers the screen with a 2D black texture with transparent holes where the lighten areas are.

As i'm using only one texture I guess that i must do this in the fragment shader, right?

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

// Texture, coordinates and size
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform vec2 textureSize;

uniform int lightCount;

struct LightSource
{
    vec2 position;
    float radius;
    float strength;
};

uniform LightSource lights[10];

void main()
{
    float alpha = 1.0;

    vec2 pos = vec2(v_texCoord.x * textureSize.x, v_texCoord.y * textureSize.y);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lightCount; i++)
    {
        LightSource source = lights[i];

        float distance = distance(source.position, pos);

        if (distance < source.radius)
        {
            alpha -= mix(source.strength, 0.0, distance/source.radius);
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha);
}
```

The problem is that the performance is really terrible (cannot run at 60fps with 2 lights and nothing else on screen), any suggestions to make it better or even different ways to approach this problem?

By the way, i'm doing this from cocos2d-x, so if anyone has any idea that uses cocos2d elements it will be welcome as well :)

Comment: What actual fps are you really getting? 60fps seems quite fast for a phone.

Comment: very irregular 40 fps with anything else at the screen

Comment: Tim, 60 fps is NOT fast for a phone. I've rendered 30 objects each with 30,000 vertices and bump maps in the iPhone5 and gotten 60 fps.  The problem is that even going back to the iPhone 4, which is 2 years prior hardware, that same app only does about 10 fps. So the newer iDevices have very fast GPU.  But right now you have to support at least back to the iPhone 4 and original iPad.  And I have yet to figure out how to determine which device you have (other than having the app try a render and check the fps).

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with Tim. If you want to improve the total speed, you've to avoid for loops. I recommend you that, if the lights array size is always ten, swap the loop statement with ten copies of the loop content. You should be aware that any variable that you declare into a loop statement will be freed up at the end of the loop! So its a good idea to span the loop in ten parts (ugly, but it's an old school trick ;))))

  Besides, I also recommend you to put some println in every statement, to see what instructions is messing around. I bet that the mix operation is the culprit. I don't know anything about cocos2d, but, it is possible to make an unique call to mix at the end of the process, with a sumarization of distances and strengths? It seems that at some point there's a pretty float-consuming annoying operation

Comment: Thing is i want to have a max of 10 lights but a variable number of them, so i don't think that i can skip that loop... Should this shader be going so slow?

Comment: The first thing you should try is determine where the CPU consumption is made. Flood your code with printf and run it. Then check the log and see what instruction is messing around

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would try (not guaranteed to help)

1. Remove the for loop and just hardcode in two lights. For loops can be expensive if they are not handled properly by the driver. It would be good to know if that is slowing you down.
2. If statements can be expensive, and I don't think that's a good application of `mix` (you're doing an `a*(1-c) + 0.0 * c`, and the second half of that term is pointless). I might try replacing this if statement:

   ```
   if (distance < source.radius)
   {
       alpha -= mix(source.strength, 0.0, distance/source.radius);
   }
   ```

   With this single line:

   ```
   alpha -= (1.0-min(distance/source.radius, 1.0)) * source.strength;
   ```

Comment: How can a for loop be expensive? O_O The if i want to have an array of light sources how can i iterate them?

Comment: Because a for loop involves branching if it is not unrolled properly, and branching is an expensive operation for a GPU. I'm not certain if this is an actual problem for you, though on some drivers it could be. It was just something to try.